# Bash script to check multiple running processes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm made the following code to determine if a process is running:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps cax | grep 'Nginx' > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Process is running."
else
  echo "Process is not running."
fi
```

I would like to use my code to check multiple processes and use a list as input (see below), but getting stuck in the foreach loop.

```
CHECK_PROCESS=nginx, mysql, etc
```

What is the correct way to use a foreach loop to check multiple processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separated list of of processes:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROC="nginx mysql ..."
for p in $PROC
do
  ps cax | grep $p > /dev/null

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Process $p is running."
  else
    echo "Process $p is not running."
  fi

done
```

If you simply want to see if either one of them is running, then you don't need loo. Just give the list to `grep`:

```
ps cax | grep -E "Nginx|mysql|etc" > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

If your system has `pgrep` installed, you'd better use it instead of the `grep`ing of the output of `ps`.

Regarding you're question, how to loop through a list of processes, you'd better use an array. A working example might be something along these lines:

(Remark: avoid capitalized variables, this is an awfully bad bash practice):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define an array of processes to be checked.
# If properly quoted, these may contain spaces
check_process=( "nginx" "mysql" "etc" )

for p in "${check_process[@]}"; do
    if pgrep "$p" > /dev/null; then
        echo "Process \`$p' is running"
    else
        echo "Process \`$p' is not running"
    fi
done
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Create file chkproc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in $@; do
    echo -n "$name: "
    pgrep $name > /dev/null && echo "running" || echo "not running"
done
```

And then run:

```
$ ./chkproc.sh nginx mysql etc
nginx: not running
mysql: running
etc: not running
```

Unless you have some old or "weird" system you should have **pgrep** available.